# SQL Server Link foreign key on join using each row on the right table only once

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE remote_clients (
   id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   first_name VARCHAR(255), 
   last_name VARCHAR(255),
   date_of_birth DATE
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE local_clients (
   id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   first_name VARCHAR(255), 
   last_name VARCHAR(255),
   date_of_birth DATE,
   remote_client_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES remote_clients(id) 
)
```

I want to link all the local_clients with a row from remote_client with matching name and date of birth, but each remote_client can only be linked with one local_client.

How can I do this in one update query?

### Examples

```
INSERT INTO local_clients
  (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar', '2020-01-01'),
  ('foo', 'bar', '2020-01-01'),
  ('baz', 'lurman', '2020-01-01'),
  ('steve', 'last', '2020-01-01'),
  ('steve', 'last', '2020-01-01'),
  ('aaron', 'something', '2020-01-01')
```

```
INSERT INTO remote_clients
  (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar', '2020-01-01'),
  ('foo', 'bar', '2020-01-01'),
  ('baz', 'lurman', '2020-01-01'),
  ('baz', 'lurman', '2020-01-01'),
  ('steve', 'last', '2020-01-01'),
```

After the update, my local_clients should look like this

| id | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth | remote_client_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | bar | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | foo | bar | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| 3 | baz | lurman | 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| 4 | aaron | something | 2020-01-01 | NULL |
| 5 | steve | last | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| 6 | steve | last | 2020-01-01 | NULL |

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @Larnu the actual tables have a length if that helps.

Comment: A column can only contain a scalar value, so your column `remote_client_id ` *can* only reference one `remote_clients`.

Comment: I mean that if there are two local_clients with details matching a remote_client, the update query should only link the first local_client and not the second.

Comment: @Larnu But multiple local clients can be linked to the same remote client, which is what I think he wants to avoid.

Comment: Exactly @sagi. Sorry if I haven't worded my question or title correctly.

Comment: @Healyhatman What does link means? you need to give some examples of what you want to accomplish. Are you looking for a select query to get the result you asked for? Or are you looking to alter the tables structure so it will only allow what you asked for? If so, what happens with a second local clients that is linked to the same remote client? And which one is consider first?

Comment: If you only want a value of `remote_client_id` to only appear once, why not use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT/INDEX`?

Comment: Probably what he needs, but maybe he means that he's already stuck in this situation and need to fix the table content first @Larnu

Comment: I already have a unique constraint on the foreign key. If I did UPDATE local_clients SET remote_client_id = a.id FROM local_clients JOIN remote_clients a ON blahblah it will try and set non-unique values and throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE local_clients
SET remote_client_id = subQuery.id
FROM local_clients
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
     local.id,
     remote.id,
     ---Get the row number, paritioned by the local ID so it's only joined once
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY local.id ORDER BY local.id) AS row_number
   FROM local_clients AS local

   INNER JOIN remote_clients AS remote ON
   local.first_name = remote.first_name AND
   local.last_name = remote.last_name AND
   local.date_of_birth = remote.date_of_birth

   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( ---The remote client isn't already linked
      SELECT remote_client_id
      FROM local_clients
      WHERE local_clients.remote_client_id = remote_clients.id
   )
) AS subQuery

WHERE NOT EXISTS ( ---The local client isn't already linked
  SELECT * FROM remote_clients WHERE local_clients.remote_client_id = remote_clients.id
)
--- If there are multiple remotes, only get the first
AND subQuery.row_number = 1
```